# Simultaneous birthday probability. Why is there an $(365-n+1)$?

Tags: probability

If $n$ people are present in a room, what is the probability that no two of them celebrate their birthday on the same day of the year? How large need $n$ be so that this probability is less than 12?

Because each person can celebrate his or her birthday on any one of 365 days, there are a total of $(365)^n$ possible outcomes. (We are ignoring the possibility of someone having been born on February 29.) Furthermore, there are $(365)(364)(363) · (365 − n + 1)$ possible outcomes that result in no two of the people having the same birthday.

But why is there a (365-n+1)?

Comment: There are $n$ factors in the product $365\times364\times363\times\dots$ so the last factor is...?

Comment: You should read what is called the "fencepost error". It might help you in many other questions, since you are having a doubt here.

Comment: Also known as the "off by one" error.  Do a few small examples and try to see a pattern.  A question based on this error is my first when interviewing programmers.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it as an *arithmetic sequence*.

$365, 364, 363, ...$
The first term $a = 365$
The common difference $d = -1$
The $n^{th} \  term = a + (n - 1)d = 365 + (n - 1)(-1) = 365 - n + 1$